# Dispatch event on body tag with another element as the target

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, dom-events

I have a client that uses EmberJS on their website. When I want to inject a value to one of the text input fields with `elem.value="##"`, it changes the text inside the field, but does not update the variables that are sent to the server. It seems like there is an event listener on the `<body>` tag that does it. Is there a way to dispatch an event on the `<body>` element with some other element as the target?

Comment: Other than using [`dispatchEvent`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)?

Comment: When using the dispatch event on the input element nothing happens...
I have tried any event that the body have listened to

Answer (score 0):

In all single-page-apps / javascript-favoring forms, you have to trigger events that the app is listening too -- usually.

Not all JS apps that submit forms use the native form submit with the FormData object, etc.

So setting the value from outside of the app's code itself will still require knowledge of how the app has implemented their form.

One option is to use
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent (as per @Sebastian's suggestion)

Comment: When using the dispatch event on the input element nothing happens...
I have tried any event that the body have listened to

Comment: which events have you tried?

Comment: I tried, change, click, input, keypress, keyup, keydown, submit

Comment: do you have access to the source code?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: can you create a reproduction?
It seems that what you need to do is *very very* specific to this specific page, and no generic implementation can help you :-\

Comment: I'm not sure I can reproduce it...
I'm trying to build a LinkedIn job posting automation, and when I get to the promotion part I want it to be on the minimum budget per day, the problem is in order to know what is the minimum I have to input a low price and only then it shows the minimum price, and after that, I need to input it and then moving forward.